# How to enable components?

Tags: modules

hello I currently use CiviCRM 4.7.29 with Drupal

I activated the CiviCase, CiviCampaign and CiviGrant components but I do not see the associated menus in the bar.

did I forget to do something?

sorry in advance if the question has been asked, I have not found an answer

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you logged in using super admin user(i.e user id = 1)?

Here are some advice to solve the issue:

1. Recheck visiting component page if the components are enabled.
2. Please check Drupal permission.
3. Clear Drupal and CiviCRM cache.
4. Check Navigation links for Grants, Case etc by navigating to Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Navigation menu
5. Do menu rebuild /civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Let us know how it goes.

Comment: it's related to the permissions granted to Drupal. I will review this point with Drupal admin. thanks again Pradeep !